# Audio Recording and Playback – Internal storage

Tags: android

I’m working on an app that needs  to record and playback several audio files.   I’d like to organize them into subdirectories under the “../files” folder as follows.   ( I’ve successfully done this onto external storage. but need to allow devices with no External storage.)

```
../files/TopicA
      Note1.3gp
      Note2.3gp
      Note3.3gp

../files/TopicB
      Note1.3gp
      Note2.3gp
      Note3.3gp
```

I can successufully record the files, but cannot play them back.   This seems to be due to the requirent of MediaPlayer needing the Files to be WORLD_READABLE. How can make the .3gp files WORLD_READABLE?  (I'm using MediaRecorder to create the files)

I tried using openFileOutput()  to copy the files and make the new file WORLD_READABLE but that does not seem to work with subdirectories.  I want to keep my target base as 2.1 so i can't use the function  setReadable()  to change the mode.

Any Suggestions?